# How to make 2D input controls in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Sorry to bother you again but since I am starting with Unity and I am very interested in developing 2D games and like the 2D Unity sample project was not designed with 2D controls, for it, I would need to make 2D input controls for the game, for it, Could anybody help me to create them for this 2D sample?
Thanks in advance.
Best Regards
Alejandro

Answer (score 4):

As a very simple answer, you should start by choosing the two axis that you wanna keep for your character's movement. As an example, you could choose to move your character along the `x` and `y` axis, ignoring the `z` one.

Then, you should map the horizontal and vertical axis input to your character's movement, putting into consideration the movement speed (that you can define as a variable) and the time elapsed between the last frame and the actual one.

So, considering to move the character on the `x` and `y` axis, you could do something similar:

```
var speed = 20.0;

function Update () {
   var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * speed;
   var y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * speed;
   transform.Translate(x, y, 0);
}
```

That can be translated in natural language as: "*at each frame (because you are in the Update() function), translate your character on the x and y axis, with respect of time elapsed between the two last frames and the speed (= 20).*"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a similar snippit of code to the previous answer just with a few minor tweaks, since you havent really specified wheter its a top-down or a platformer type game here is the code i suggest in c#

```
public float speed;                //Floating point variable to store the player's movement speed.

private Rigidbody2D rb2d;        //Store a reference to the Rigidbody2D component required to use 2D Physics.

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    //Get and store a reference to the Rigidbody2D component so that we can access it.
    rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
}

//FixedUpdate is called at a fixed interval and is independent of frame rate. Put physics code here.
void FixedUpdate()
{
    //Store the current horizontal input in the float moveHorizontal.
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");

    //Store the current vertical input in the float moveVertical.
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

    //Use the two store floats to create a new Vector2 variable movement.
    Vector2 movement = new Vector2 (moveHorizontal, moveVertical);

    //Call the AddForce function of our Rigidbody2D rb2d supplying movement multiplied by speed to move our player.
    rb2d.AddForce (movement * speed);
}
```

If you did mean a more platformer based movement then please do let me know i could supply you code for that as well! One thing to note is that i used public before defining speed because that allows you to tweak the value in the unity gui, its useful for testing purposes. I found this code in one of my previous projects and it works fine there so it should work you.