# How to Move the position of a GameObject independently to its rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, controls

I am creating a 3d top-down game, I have got the controls working for the gameobject and then got the rotation of the gameobject pointing to the mouse

though as I assumed, the controls of direction (w being up, s being down, etc) are affected due to the rotation so if it is being rotated 180 degrees, w is moving it down.

```
var dir = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
transform.Translate(dir * _speed * Time.deltaTime);

GameObjectPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
MousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

float ObjectToMouseX = GameObjectPosition.x - MousePosition.x;
float ObjectToMouseY = GameObjectPosition.y - MousePosition.y;

float GameOjectAngle = -90-(float)Mathf.Atan2(ObjectToMouseY, ObjectToMouseX)*(180/Mathf.PI);
Vector3 GameObjectRotation = new Vector3(0, GameOjectAngle, 0);

transform.eulerAngles = GameObjectRotation;
```

this is what my code is so far

I haven't even tried to attempt this problem more so because I dont really know where to start

Comment: Separate your rotation and input into two different variables.
Combine them where appropriate.

I.e. LookLeft() will change camera 180 degrees, LookRight() 90

Then a GetCameraAngleYAxis() will return -90 (the top down perspective)

Comment: By any chance could you show it as a code block? could just be the time of the day though I'm struggling to understand.

Comment: I don't have time, do these help? If not, I can write something up later

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745526/how-to-make-2d-input-controls-in-unity

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3zxTigjJr24

Comment: actually, could I create a parent and separate the movement controls and rotation controls?

Comment: that was what I was getting at, yes. Your (movement) inputs are 2D, your rotation is another dimension. You want to treat them separately.

Comment: ah ok cheers for that, yeah I tested it out and it ended up working just fine